# Azure storage table powershell customfilter which matches everything

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-table-storage

How can I create a customfilter which matches everything? For example, check if etag or timestamp is not empty? My plan is to have that as placeholder and dynamically add more filters after it. Similary to how I would put in SQL query "1=1" which gives me the possibility to continue that query later.

Comment: If you don't specify any query that means it will find all entities.

Comment: but how do I set empty filter?

Comment: You don't :). `$filter` is an optional request parameter.

Comment: that is my problem. I want to use that customfilter so I need to have that switch on my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a customfilter which matches everything?

You don't really need to create any special filter. Absence of a filter would mean all entities are fetched.

However based on your comments, if you still want to have a filter you can define the same on `Timestamp` system attribute. It will always be present on every entity. So your default filter criteria could be:

```
Timestamp gt datetime'2000-01-01T00:00:00Z'
```

However please keep in mind that if your query doesn't include `PartitionKey`, a full table scan will be performed so when you do write your actual query, please make sure to remove this default filter criteria (which brings me back to the point of not defining the default criteria in the first place :)).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have similar example how I could check if for example, the etag field is not empty or null?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to query on etag field.